# What does falling to a team in basketball games mean?

Tags: meaning, sports

This is the sentence I have problems with:

> It was the second straight overtime game for Tulsa, which fell to
> Washington on Monday.

source:[link to article](http://www.nj.com/knicks/index.ssf/2013/05/cappie_pondexter_jumper_lifts.html)

Obviously it's a sports report about WNBA.

What does *fall to* mean here? Is it a technical term specific to sports?

Comment: "fell to" means they "lost to", just sport-writerese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an extension of the usage  of fall referring to  sports  events meaning “to be defeated”:

To fall:

> to succumb to attack:
>   *The city fell to the enemy.*

(Dictionary.com)